# Issue when deleting top 18000 rows from SQLite (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database for my Android app which is created as such:

```
String CREATE_TABLE_GYRO = "CREATE TABLE gyro ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "timestamp BIGINT NOT NULL, " +
                "x FLOAT NOT NULL, " +
                "y FLOAT NOT NULL, " +
                "z FLOAT NOT NULL)";
```

I want to delete the first 18000 entries in my database. I do this using the following code and query:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
System.out.println("Database size before delete: " + getSize());
database.rawQuery("DELETE FROM gyro WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM gyro ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 18000)", null);
System.out.println("Database size after delete: " + getSize());
```

However, nothing appears to happen. Here is the output:

```
Database size before delete: 10665984
Database size after delete: 10665984
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `execSQL()` and not `rawQuery()` for SQL like this.

`rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL but does not execute it until one of the `moveTo..()` methods is invoked on the returned `Cursor`. `execSQL()` both compiles and runs the SQL.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot. I'll be sure to note the difference between execSQL and rawQuery :)